# Add values of an array inside a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I created a hash that has an array as a value.

```
{
  "0":[0,14,0,14],
  "1":[0,14],
  "2":[0,11,0,12],
  "3":[0,11,0,12],
  "4":[0,10,0,13,0,11],
  "5":[0,10,0,14,0,0,0,11,12,0],
  "6":[0,0,12],
  "7":[],
  "8":[0,14,0,12],
  "9":[0,14,0,0,11,14],
  "10":[0,11,0,12],
  "11":[0,13,0,14]
}
```

I want the sum of all values in each array. I expect to have such output as:

```
{
  "0":[24],
  "1":[14],
  "2":[23],
  "3":[23],
  "4":[34],
  "5":[47],
  "6":[12],
  "7":[],
  "8":[26],
  "9":[39],
  "10":[23],
  "11":[27]
}
```

I do not know how to proceed from here. Any pointers are thankful.

Comment: Your hash syntax is invalid, use `=>` instead of `:`

Comment: this is the output I show after using to_json, so it is converted json form

Comment: @Stefan Now it is not.

Comment: @user3290805 What do you mean "how to proceed from here"? You haven't proceeded at all.

Comment: it is for sure, i just check but plain hash looks like this...
 {0=>[0, 0, 12, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 15, 15, 0, 0, 12, 12, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 10, 0, 10, 0, 12, 11, 11, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0], 1=>[14, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 14, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 11, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 11, 11, 10]

Comment: @user3290805 What do you mean by "plain hash"? Don't provide another hash. Don't change what you are asking for.

Comment: To everyone: It is amazing that a beginner like the OP knows more than many experienced users here, but if you don't know it, here is a hint: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4935.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It works on ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux].

Comment: Ah, ruby 2.2. That's still too new :)

Comment: @sawa thanks for pointing that out, I've totally overlooked that ... "feature".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
hash = { "0" => [0,14,0,14], "1" => [0,14], "7" => [] }

hash.each { |k, v| hash[k] = Array(v.reduce(:+)) }
# => { "0" => [28], "1" => [14], "7" => [] }
```

Comment: So far it is the only answer that got the values correct, but your keys are not what the OP has. Hint: Ruby 2.2, https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4935.

Comment: this currently returns `[[28], [14], []]`

Comment: @spickermann could you please elaborate `{ |_, v| Array(v.reduce(:+)) }` code ? or any good link so that i can understand .

Comment: @spickermann is `Hash#map` supposed to return a hash in Ruby >= 2.2?

Comment: How you got the Hash back, in your last example ? I 'm not getting.

Comment: @Stefan He missed `#to_h`... And he should mention it is as `2.1>=` .. :)

Comment: My last example was just wrong. I removed it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

For `hash` object you as this one.

```
hash = {"0"=>[0,14,0,14],"1"=>[0,14],"2"=>[0,11,0,12],"3"=>[0,11,0,12],"4"=>[0,10,0,13,0,11],"5"=>[0,10,0,14,0,0,0,11,12,0],"6"=>[0,0,12],"7"=>[],"8"=>[0,14,0,12],"9"=>[0,14,0,0,11,14],"10"=>[0,11,0,12],"11"=>[0,13,0,14]}
```

You could change value of each `k => v` pair

```
hash.each_pair do |k, v|
  hash[k] = [v.reduce(0, :+)]
end
```

will resolve in

```
hash = {"0"=>[28], "1"=>[14], "2"=>[23], "3"=>[23], "4"=>[34], "5"=>[47], "6"=>[12], "7"=>[0], "8"=>[26], "9"=>[39], "10"=>[23], "11"=>[27]}
```

Comment: Your hash is different from both the one OP has in the question and the one OP presented in a comment.

Comment: Even if the key difference is ignored, this is incorrect. Hint: `hash["7"]`. It can be fixed though. Hint: "initial value", "splat".

Answer (score 0):

Classic example for map/reduce. You need to iterate on the hash keys and values (`map {|k,v|}`), and for each value count the sum using `reduce(0) {|acc, x| acc+x}`

```
h = {1 => [1,2,3], 2 => [3,4,5], 7 => []} #example
a = h.map {|k,v| [k ,v.reduce(0) {|acc, x| acc+x}] }
=> [[1, 6], [2, 12], [7, 0]]
Hash[a]
=> {1=>6, 2=>12, 7=>0}
```

Comment: Your use of `flatten` and `*` are not necessary.

Comment: This is incorrect. Hint: `h[7]`. It can be fixed though. Hint: "initial value", "splat".

Comment: @sawa, `[].reduce(0) { |acc, x| acc+x }` will return `0`, so what's wrong with `h[7]`?

Answer (score 0):

If your string is just like you mentioned you can parse it using JSON, or jump that step if you have already an Hash.
You can check the documentation of inject [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
require 'json'
json_string =  '
{
  "0":[0,14,0,14],
  "1":[0,14],
  "2":[0,11,0,12],
  "3":[0,11,0,12],
  "4":[0,10,0,13,0,11],
  "5":[0,10,0,14,0,0,0,11,12,0],
  "6":[0,0,12],
  "7":[],
  "8":[0,14,0,12],
  "9":[0,14,0,0,11,14],
  "10":[0,11,0,12],
  "11":[0,13,0,14]
}
'
hash = JSON.parse json_string

result = Hash.new

hash.each do |key, value|

  result[key] = value.inject(:+)

end

puts result.inspect
```

and the result:

```
{"0"=>28, "1"=>14, "2"=>23, "3"=>23, "4"=>34, "5"=>47, "6"=>12, "7"=>nil, "8"=>26, "9"=>39, "10"=>23, "11"=>27}
```

Comment: The OP did not say it is JSON. The OP could actually be dealing with JSON, but since the OP did not mention that, you should assume what OP presented. Hint: Ruby 2.2.

Comment: And the result you have is closer to the expected result than the other two answers so far posted in some sense, but it is far away in another sense.

Comment: @sawa If i am not wrong then format of data is Json Right ?

Comment: @sawa based [on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340573/add-values-of-an-array-inside-a-hash#comment45026238_28340573) *"this is the output I show after using to_json, so it is converted json form"* [and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340573/add-values-of-an-array-inside-a-hash#comment45026423_28340573) *"plain hash looks like this... {0=>[0, 0, 12, ..."*, I'd say the OP posted JSON output. It is coincidence that this is a valid hash in Ruby 2.2.

Comment: @Stefan: agree, pure coincidence. :)

Comment: @Stefan I see. I missed those comments. Sorry. Now, it is the OP who is to be blamed. The OP made no reference to JSON in the question.